# Forcing Webservice to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS ends badly

Tags: c#, web-services, http-post, redirect, http-get

i am trying to invoke a webservice (WSDL, language:c#) located behind a load balancer.
The load balancer does not accept any http invokation, thus it redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

BTW when I invoke the webservice using the HTTP (it's an old one!) I see the following behavior:

1. The request is sent to the balancer using HTTP, Request Method: Post;
2. The balancer's response says redirect to HTTPS;
3. The Web Service Client sends again the request using HTTPS but the Request Method changes to GET, and it clearly fails!

What is the reason that brings the Request Method to change? Is there any way to make it works?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your load balancer is misconfigured.

Comment: All redirects will result in a (second) GET request to the target URL. It sounds like what you really want to do is forward the initial request on, not return a redirect instruction to the client. Or, in the case of HTTPS, your best bet is to return a redirect to HTTPS from the initial GET request when the page was loaded (from the app, not the load balancer). You shouldn't be redirecting to HTTPS from a POST. If you receive a POST in HTTP to a resource that only accepts HTTPS the correct response is to return an error because it shouldn't have happened in the first place.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: thanks for your answer. Any way to fix this? Maybe replacing 302 error with 303 could be a solution....?